# Nats request/reply in Java

Tags: java, events, messaging, nats.io

I've previous Kafka knowledge and I've been playing around with Nats.io which seems a really solid choice for messaging.

In particular, I'm interested in the well-documented Request/Reply mechanism but I've had difficulties correctly implementing it in Java with the Jnats driver.

This is my Connector:

```
 // Single server nats connection
    @PostConstruct
    public void connect() throws ExternalServiceUnavailableException {

        Options options = new Options.Builder()
                .server(connectionString)
                .maxReconnects(20)
                .reconnectWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .connectionListener((conn, type) -> {
                    if (type == ConnectionListener.Events.CONNECTED) {
                        LOG.info("Connected to Nats Server");
                    } else if (type == ConnectionListener.Events.RECONNECTED) {
                        LOG.info("Reconnected to Nats Server");
                    } else if (type == ConnectionListener.Events.DISCONNECTED) {
                        LOG.error("Disconnected to Nats Server, reconnect attempt in seconds");
                    } else if (type == ConnectionListener.Events.CLOSED) {
                        LOG.info("Closed connection with Nats Server");
                    }
                })
                .build();


        try {
            connection = Nats.connect(options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to connect to Nats Server");
            throw new ExternalServiceUnavailableException(ExternalServiceUnavailableException.Service.NATS);
        }

    }
```

This is the request method (with very high await time for testing purposes):

```
 public Optional<String> asyncRequest(String topic, String message) throws ExternalServiceUnavailableException {

        Future<Message> reply = natsConnector.getConnection().request(topic, message.getBytes());
        try {

            Message msg = reply.get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            LOG.info(new String(msg.getData()));

            return Optional.of(new String(msg.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Unable to retrieve response for the sent request: " + message);
            throw new ExternalServiceUnavailableException(ExternalServiceUnavailableException.Service.NATS);
        }

    }
```

And this is the Response Handler with the reply mechanism:

```
 @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = natsConnector.getConnection().createDispatcher(message -> {
        });

        Subscription assetsInfo = dispatcher.subscribe("assets-info", message -> {
        JSONObject requestMessage = new JSONObject(new String(message.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            if (requestMessage.getString("requestType").equals("stock-status")) {

                if (requestMessage.getString("of").equals("all")) {

                    JSONObject response = assetQuery.retrieveYesterdayStockStatus();
                    LOG.info("response ready");
                    natsOperation.publishEvent("assets-info", response);
                    LOG.info("message sent");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

My two independent Services communicate via a dockerized Nats.io, and I can correctly check via the Nats Go client that messages have been sent by both Services on the same topic.

Unfortunately, the "Requestor" when invokes the `asyncRequest` function doesn't quite handle the reply even with very high await in the `reply.get(...)`.

When I try to evaluate the `reply` Object in debug mode, it does not have any data in it and shows a `TimeoutException`.

At `msg.getData()` the program crashes.

Do you guys have any hints for me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your "replyer" code to publish to the replyTo subject from the original message.

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    Dispatcher dispatcher = natsConnector.getConnection().createDispatcher(message -> {});

    Subscription assetsInfo = dispatcher.subscribe("assets-info", message -> {
        JSONObject requestMessage = new JSONObject(
            new String(message.getData(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        );

        if (requestMessage.getString("requestType").equals("stock-status")) {
            if (requestMessage.getString("of").equals("all")) {
                JSONObject response = assetQuery.retrieveYesterdayStockStatus();
                LOG.info("response ready");
                //See Change Here
                natsOperation.publish(message.getReplyTo(), response);
                LOG.info("message sent");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The request reply mechanism is looking for a single response on the generated replyTo subject.

See https://docs.nats.io/nats-concepts/reqreply